# Theano import error: No module named cPickle

Tags: python, python-2.7, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network

```
>>> import theano
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
from theano.gof import (
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from theano.gof.cc import \
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 30, in <module>
from theano.gof import link
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 18, in <module>
from theano.gof.type import Type
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/type.py", line 17, in <module>
from theano.gof.op import CLinkerObject
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 25, in <module>
from theano.gof.cmodule import GCC_compiler
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 8, in <module>
import six.moves.cPickle as pickle
ImportError: No module named cPickle
```

I'm pretty sure **there is no problem with cPickle**. Can it be the problem of other dependencies? It's true that I upgraded all the packages this morning, so that a conflict of version may occur. Nonetheless, the problem still exists after I switched to the bleeding-edge version of theano. Would someone help me figure it out?

PS: My developing device is Macbook Pro 13(early 2015); my system version is OS X 10.10.5; python version is 2.7.10

=========================== Second Edit ===================================

It seems I do have latest version of six installed on my Mac.

```
YiqundeMacBook-Pro:~ Leo$ pip show six
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: six
Version: 1.9.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: `six` is a compatibility package between Python 2 and Python 3 code. For some reason it doesn't determine you have `cPickle` module available even though Python 2 always has it. I suggest you open the `six.moves` source and try to figure what's going on there.

Comment: There is no `six.moves` source and the way `six` "determines" if `cPickle` is available is essentially hardcoded into it based on whether it's running under Python 2 or 3. Make sure you have the latest version of `six` (1.9.0) installed. If so, report the problem as a bug via [https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six).

Comment: @martineau     I'm sure I have the latest version of 'six'.(see my latest update of the question)

Comment: Then it looks like a bug in `six` to me because the `import six.moves.cPickle as pickle` should work based on the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves) and source code for it I've looked at — so I think you should report it as such to let Benjamin (the author) know. You may be able to work around the problem by changing the `cmodule.py` source yourself (to just `import cPickle as pickle` since you're using Python 2).

Comment: I have the same issue with CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and *upgrading* six solved issue:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid using `sudo` at all costs. Open a python session and run

```
import six
print six.__version__
print six.__file__
```

The version will likely not be most recent (1.10.0), so go manually delete the six.py and six.pyc files at the imported path, and then run `pip install six`. Python should now be importing the latest version of six, compatible with Theano :)