# error using ete3 in python: 'No module name cPickle'

Tags: python-2.7, etetoolkit, ete3

I'm having a problem similar to:
[Theano import error: No module named cPickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679476/theano-import-error-no-module-named-cpickle)

But with using ete3 (www.etetoolkit.org). I downgraded to ete2 and the problem disappeared, but would like to be using the functionality in ete3.

Following after the comments in the related stackoverflow post above, i've upgraded to the newest version of 'six' (1.10.0), but still have this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "treebuilder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ete3 import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ete3/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .webplugin.webapp import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ete3/webplugin/webapp.py", line 46, in <module>
    import six.moves.cPickle
ImportError: No module named cPickle
```

and, when I try to install cPickle (using sudo and -H), I get:

```
Collecting cPickle
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cPickle (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cPickle
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: My colleague fixed my problem by upgrading the 3.5, but the answer still eludes us without that fix.